# Problem about Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable set and let

$$
B = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x+q \in A \text{ for some q} \in \mathbb{Q}\}.
$$

Prove that $m(B^c)=0$ if and only if $m(A)>0$.

I already showed that if $m(B^c)=0$, then $m(A)>0$ in this way:

\begin{align*}
B &= \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x+q \in A \text{ for some q} \in \mathbb{Q}\}.\\ &= \cup_{q \in Q} \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x+q  \in A \} \\ &\leq  \sum_{i=1}^\infty m(\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x+q_i \in A \}) = \infty \cdot m(A)
\end{align*}

If $m(A)=0$, then $m(\mathbb{R})=0$ (contradiction). Therefore $m(A) > 0 $.

But I could find a way to prove opposite way. How can I show that if $m(A) >0$, then $m(B^c)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $m(A)>0$. It suffices to show that $m\big(I\setminus \bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}(q+A)\big)=0$, where $I=(-a,a)$ with $a>0$. Note that for any $0<\epsilon<1$, there exists an interval $J$ such that $m(J\setminus A)\le \epsilon m(J)$ and $m(J)$ is small relative to $m(I)$. Next, we choose $q_1,\ldots, q_n\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$
I\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n (q_i+J) \quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{i=1}^n m(q_i+J)\le 2m(I).
$$
Consequently,
$$
m\!\left(I\setminus \bigcup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}} (q+A) \right)\le m\!\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n (q_i+J)\setminus(q_i+A) \right)\le 2\epsilon m(I).
$$
The result follows by sending $\epsilon\to 0$.

---

The last inequality holds because $I\setminus \bigcup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}} (q+A)\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^n (q_i+J)\setminus(q_i+A)$ and
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n m\!\left((q_i+J)\setminus(q_i+A)\right)\le \epsilon\sum_{i=1}^n m(q_i+J)\le 2\epsilon m(I).
$$

Comment: why the last inequality hold?

Comment: @someeed I added some details.